# Django df add filter to df column

Tags: python, html, django, filter

I am new to Django. I have a df and I can display it in the html. I use the pandas.read_sql_query to pull the data from the db. I want to realize the filter for each column in the df.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    dfa_query = "select * from database"
    dfa = pandas.read_sql_query(dfa_query,connection)
    dfa_html = dfa.to_html(index=False)
    return render(request, 'CaseTest.html',{'dfa':dfa_html})
```

**CaseTest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CaseTest</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> dfa </h2>
<div style="height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
{{dfa | safe}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

THe filter function I want to realize is sth like excel filter, for each column there is a drop down menu and you can choose the value you want, then the df will only show the value which matches the requirements.

for the display for filter, I am okay with any format
(1) the filter in excel
(2) the filter on the top of the table, see picture below

[image: example]

**Any help is really appreciated!!**